# Need Help With FetchedResultsController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I had a tableview that was populated from an array which was populated from fetched results.

Now I'm trying to just use the FetchedResultsController the way Apple recommends and not use a separate array to load the data.

In this conversion process, I am now stuck.  I need to remove all references to eventsArray and use the FechedObjects property of the FetchedResultsController.  If anyone could help me with this, this would be great.

Here is my code:

```
@implementation RoutineTableViewController

@synthesize routineTableView;
@synthesize eventsArray;
@synthesize entered;
@synthesize managedObjectContext;
@synthesize fetchedResultsController=__fetchedResultsController;

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    if (managedObjectContext == nil) 
    { 
        managedObjectContext = [(CurlAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext]; 
    }

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Routine" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [request setEntity:entity];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
    if (mutableFetchResults == nil) {
        // Handle the error.
    }
    [self setEventsArray:mutableFetchResults];
    [mutableFetchResults release];
    [request release];

    UIBarButtonItem * addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(showPrompt)];
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:addButton];
    [addButton release];

    UIBarButtonItem *editButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Edit" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(toggleEdit)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editButton;
    [editButton release];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    self.eventsArray = nil;
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

-(void)toggleEdit
{
    [self.routineTableView setEditing: !self.routineTableView.editing animated:YES];

    if (self.routineTableView.editing)
        [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Done"];
    else
        [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Edit"];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [__fetchedResultsController release];
    [managedObjectContext release];
    [eventsArray release];
    [entered release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Add an event

-(void)addEvent
{    
    Routine *routine = (Routine *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Routine" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

    routine.name=entered;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) 
    {
        // Handle the error.
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", error);

    [eventsArray addObject:routine];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];

    //[self.routineTableView reloadData];

    NSInteger lastSection = [self.routineTableView numberOfSections] -1;


    [self.routineTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self.routineTableView numberOfRowsInSection:lastSection]-1 inSection:lastSection] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
}
/*
- (void)insertNewObject
{
    // Create a new instance of the entity managed by the fetched results controller.
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchRequest] entity];
    NSManagedObject *newManagedObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[entity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];

    // If appropriate, configure the new managed object.
    // Normally you should use accessor methods, but using KVC here avoids the need to add a custom class to the template.
    [newManagedObject setValue:[NSDate date] forKey:@"timeStamp"];

    // Save the context.
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error])
    {
        /*
         Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

         abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. If it is not possible to recover from the error, display an alert panel that instructs the user to quit the application by pressing the Home button.
         */
/*
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
}
*/

-(void)showPrompt
{
    AlertPrompt *prompt = [AlertPrompt alloc];
    prompt = [prompt initWithTitle:@"Add Workout Day" message:@"\n \n Please enter title for workout day" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" okButtonTitle:@"Add"];
    [prompt show];
    [prompt release];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{

    if (buttonIndex != [alertView cancelButtonIndex])
    {
        entered = [(AlertPrompt *)alertView enteredText];

        if(eventsArray && entered)
        {
            [self addEvent];

        }
    }
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    Routine *tempRoutine = (Routine *)[eventsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = tempRoutine.name;
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    return cell;
}

// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {

     if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

         // Delete the managed object for the given index path
         NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
         [context deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];

         // Update the array and table view.
         [eventsArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:YES];

         // Commit the change.
         NSError *error = nil;
         if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
             // Handle the error.
         }
     }
 }

- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSManagedObject *managedObject = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [[managedObject valueForKey:@"name"] description];
}

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
*/

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    /*
     <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
     // ...
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
     [detailViewController release];
     */
}

#pragma mark - Fetched results controller

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (__fetchedResultsController != nil)
    {
        return __fetchedResultsController;
    }

    /*
     Set up the fetched results controller.
     */
    // Create the fetch request for the entity.
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Routine" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Root"];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    [aFetchedResultsController release];
    [fetchRequest release];
    [sortDescriptor release];
    [sortDescriptors release];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error])
    {
        /*
         Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

         abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. If it is not possible to recover from the error, display an alert panel that instructs the user to quit the application by pressing the Home button.
         */
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return __fetchedResultsController;
}    

#pragma mark - Fetched results controller delegate

- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.routineTableView beginUpdates];
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
           atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
{
    switch(type)
    {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.routineTableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.routineTableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
    UITableView *tableView = self.routineTableView;

    switch(type)
    {

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.routineTableView endUpdates];
}

/*
 // Implementing the above methods to update the table view in response to individual changes may have performance implications if a large number of changes are made simultaneously. If this proves to be an issue, you can instead just implement controllerDidChangeContent: which notifies the delegate that all section and object changes have been processed. 

 - (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
 {
 // In the simplest, most efficient, case, reload the table view.
 [self.tableView reloadData];
 }
 */

@end
```

Error:

```
 2011-04-14 00:35:14.668 Curl[9389:207] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1448.89/UITableView.m:995
2011-04-14 00:35:14.671 Curl[9389:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (7) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (7), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted).'
```

Comment: why don't you use FetchedResultsController directly rather than eventsArray?

Comment: Thats what I am trying to do, Ravin

Comment: My question is why are you still having eventsArray? in cellForRowAtIndexPath you are setting text using eventsArray but in other dataSource methods you are using  FetchedResultsController. why don't you use it from start?

Comment: I was using eventsArray for everything previously.  I want to get rid of everything having to do with eventsArray and use FetchedResultsController.  I don't know how to set the text using FetchedResultsController which is why I still have eventsArray there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }


    Routine *tempRoutine = (Routine *)[yourFetchController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = tempRoutine.name;
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    return cell;
}
```

or

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }


    NSManagedObject *managedObject = [<#Fetched results controller#> objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = managedObject.name;
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    return cell;
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        // Delete the managed object for the given index path
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
        [context deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];

        // Update the array and table view.
        //[eventsArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            // Handle the error.
        }
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:YES];

        // Commit the change.
        NSError *error = nil;

    }
```

to disable sorting comment follwoing line in `- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController` method.

```
 // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:NO];
        NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

        [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

Comment: This fixes the issue, thanks. I just need to get rid of the rest of the references to eventsArray now.

Comment: In the `addEvent` method, what should I do with `[eventsArray addObject:routine];`?

Comment: comment it and try. main thing is updating the data and reloading table.

Comment: I'm still getting problems with the rest of the places were eventsArray was. such as in the delete row and the `viewDidLoad`'s `[self setEventsArray:mutableFetchResults];`

Comment: Actually I commented that viewDidLoad line out and it seems to make no difference.  When i delete cells from the table however, I need to fix the following line: `[eventsArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`

Comment: That last code is used in `-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` mehod

Comment: I already tried that, then it simply crashes when I try to delete a cell.

Comment: do we have still some dependency on eventsArray? ok you can try this one I am updating on above code

Comment: I'm getting error at line `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths: withAnimations:`  I am posting error in question as its too long here.

Comment: can you please check whether  [context deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
 line deletes the object or not. we are having problem with fetchResultsController array data updation.

Comment: NSLog(@"fetched results : \n%@\n",[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects]);

Comment: Ok, I tried deleting an object, the app crashes, but before it crashes it logs the output, and the cell i deleted is showing in the log output.

Comment: did you put line just before deleteRowsAtIndexPaths: or above save method call?

Comment: I put it right after the following line: `[context deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];` which is before `[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:YES];`.

Comment: ok then comment [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:YES]; line as well and try does it reload table automatically ? as you said in earlier comment it shows the deleted row also it means fetchedResultController data is not updated.

Comment: ok i did that and everything seems to be working now, thanks!

Comment: One last thing if you can help.  Right now it is sorting the list by alphabetical, Z is at the top, A at the bottom.  I just want to sort it by when it was inserted.  Like first added cell should be 1, 2nd 2, 3rd 3, etc.